# How do we implement a regular expression to parse and group parts of a string that may or may not exclude a specific phrase?

Tags: regex

Given the following examples, how can we parse it into groups that may/may not include other phrases?

What we need:

```
    (Text: any number of words) (LocationIndicator: 0 or 1 @) (Location: any number of words)
```

Examples:

```
    "meet me @home":
            <Text>="meet me"
            <LocationIndicator>="@"
            <Location>="home"
    "meet me in the kitchen @home":
            <Text>="meet me in the kitchen"
            <LocationIndicator>="@"
            <Location>="home"
    "     meet me       @      home      ":
            <Text>="meet me"
            <LocationIndicator>="@"
            <Location>="home"
    "meet me":
            <Text>="meet me"
            <LocationIndicator>=""
            <Location>=""
```

This regex does what we need, but only if we include the @ phrase:

```
    ^\s*(((?<Text>.*)?)\s*((?<LocationIndicator>(?:@)+?)\s*(?<Location>.*)))\s*$
```

If we exclude the @ phrase, we get no matches.  In other words, this fails to match/group:

```
    "meet me":
            <Text>="meet me"
            <LocationIndicator>=""
            <Location>=""
```

We've tried including a ? after the LocationIndicator/Location group, but that groups the phrase with the Text:

```
    ^\s*(((?<Text>.*)?)\s*((?<LocationIndicator>(?:@)+?)\s*(?<Location>.*))?)\s*$

    "meet me @home":
            <Text>="meet me @home"
            <LocationIndicator>=""
            <Location>=""
```

How can we match all of the examples given with a single expression?

NOTE: We are using these regular expressions in C#

Comment: You will find this very hard with just regex. Have you looked into a parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going in the right direction, adding the `?`.  What you have to do, additionally, is replace (at least) the first wildcard match, `.*`, with something that excludes your location indicator, e.g. `[^@]*`.

Edit: I simplified your expression (there were some extra parentheses and an unnecessary non-greedy-fier) and tested it.

```
^\s*(?<Text>[^@]*)?\s*(?:(?<LocationIndicator>[@]+)\s*(?<Location>.*))?\s*$
```

See http://rubular.com/r/C5lfx9cvtZ.

Comment: Since your regex is anchored and covers both with/without @, its better to give it a chance to trim spaces: `^\s*(?<Text>[^@]*?)\s*(?:(?<LocationIndicator>[@]+)\s*(?<Location>.*?))?\s*$`

Comment: Though it's not glamorous, we found that this expression works:

         ^\s*(((?<Text>.*))\s*((?<LocationIndicator>(?:@)+?)\s*(?<Location>.*)$)|((?<Text>.*)))\s*$

Basically, check for "meet me @home" then using the OR indicator (|) for "meet me".  The less-complex part of the expression must be after the more-complex version for this to work.  Yours looks much more simple, so we'll give that one a shot, though.